# Conditional sum based on boolean column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using [chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) with [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) to build charts:

```
line_chart @product.stocks.group_by_date(:date).sum(:quantity)
```

This is working fine but i'm getting wrong data because in the `stocks` table the `quantity` is depending on another column `stock_in` which is `boolean`.

- The `quantity` can't be stored as negative number, only positive numbers are supported.
- When retrieving the `quantity` we check the `stock_in` boolean to calculate sum of the quantity of a product

#### Example:

```
product_id  |  quantity  |  stock_in  |  date

1              32           true         13-06-2015
1              8            true         13-06-2015
1              10           false        13-06-2015
```

Here the quantity is calculated this way: `32 + 8 - 10 = 30`

When using

```
line_chart @product.stocks.group_by_date(:date).sum(:quantity)
```

the quantities sum of the date 13-06-2015 is 40 which is wrong

How can I fix it? Something like:

```
line_chart @product.stocks.group_by_date(:date).sum { |s| s.stock_in? ? s.quantity : -1 * s.quantity }
```

Comment: what database are you using?  MySQL? Postresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform the sum in PostgreSQL (and not the rails app), you can do :

```
line_chart @product.stocks
                   .group_by_date(:date)
                   .sum("quantity * (case stock_in when TRUE then 1 else -1 end)")
```

Comment: agreed. this belongs on the database side

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
@product.stocks.group_by_date(:date)
        .sum("case when stock_in then quantity else -quantity end")
```

Comment: I' getting PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "stocks.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function